# How to merge two lists based on the enumeration number?

Tags: python

How to merge two enumerated lists, if the first number is the same change the element from 'list 1' with element from 'list 2'?

List 1:

```
[(1, 'a’), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:09,680\n']), (3, 'b), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd’),
 (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:13,309\n']), (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g'),
 (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:15,630\n'])]
```

List 2:

```
[(2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']),
 (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309'])]
```

Result:

```
[(1, 'a’), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (3, 'b), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd’),
 (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']),  (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g'),
 (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309'])]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: convert lists to dicts; first dict update using second dict; convert first list back to list; sort list.

Answer (score 2):

Convert lists to dicts.

First dict update using second dict.

Convert first list back to list.

Sort list.

```
a = [(1, 'a'), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:09,680\n']), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd'), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:13,309\n']), (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g'), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:15,630\n'])]
b = [(2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309'])]
c = [(1, 'a'), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd'), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']),  (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g'), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309'])]

da = {k:v for k,v in a}
db = {k:v for k,v in b}
da.update(db)

x = sorted((k,v) for k,v in da.items())

print(x == c) # True
```

---

**EDIT:** as @jferard pointed out in the comment I could write it simpler

```
da = dict(a)
db = dict(b)
da.update(db)

x = sorted(da.items())

print(x == c) # True
```

Or

```
x = sorted({k:v for k,v in a+b}.items())

print(x == c) # True
```

or even

```
x = sorted(dict(a+b).items())

print(x == c) # True
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `{k:v for k,v in a}` instead of `dict(a)`? BTW `d = {k:v for k,v in a+b}` should work.

Comment: @jferard it is habit - I mostly use this to create dict and change values in one step - like `{k:v.strip().split(",") for k,v in a}` :) Now I see I could simply use `dict(a)` and `list(da.item())` :)

Comment: Can't upvote twice, but `sorted(dict(a+b).items())` is **the** answer. In Python >= 3.6, `sorted` might be unnecessary.

Comment: @jferard I also expected that in >= 3.6 it should work without `sorted()` but  I tested on 3.7 and it needed `sorted()`

Comment: Good to know. I'm not very confident with insertion ordered dicts.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is slightly different than the other answers here, but I think it gets the desired functionality and is one less dictionary conversion.

I changed the second list into a dict, then did a list comprehension to create a new list. I kept the first entry in the tuple, and did a `dict.get()` to try and get a value from the second list:

```
dict_b = {i: j for i,j in b}
new_a = [(i, dict_b.get(i, j)) for i, j in a]
```

You also don't have to re-sort the list. This leads to slightly better run times:

```
def func_1():
    dict_b = {i: j for i,j in b}
    return [(i, dict_b.get(i, j)) for i, j in a]

%timeit func_1()

2.48 µs ± 506 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


def func_2():
    da = {k:v for k,v in a}
    db = {k:v for k,v in b}
    da.update(db)

    return sorted((k,v) for k,v in da.items())

%timeit func_2()

3.07 µs ± 71.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
>>> a = [(1, 'a'), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:09,680\n']), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd'), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:13,309\n']), (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g'), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:15,630\n'])]
>>> b = [(2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309'])]
>>> seen = set()
>>> sorted(v for v in b+a if not (v[0] in seen or seen.add(v[0])))
[(1, 'a'), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd'), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']), (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g'), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309'])]
```

We consider the elements of `b` before the elements of `a` (`for v in b+a`) and use the trick to get unique elements in the order of apparition: if `v[0] in seen`, we yield `v`, else we add `v[0]` to `seen` (`seen.add(v[0])` performs a side effect and is always evaluated to `False`).

If your not interested in the result order:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [v for v in b+a if not (v[0] in seen or seen.add(v[0]))]
[(2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760']), (6, ['00:00:08,760', '00:00:09,680']), (10, ['00:00:09,680', '00:00:13,309']), (1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'd'), (7, 'e'), (8, 'f'), (9, 'g')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the key keyword with sorted().

```
list = list1 + list2
print (sorted([list], key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

key should be a function that identifies how to retrieve the comparable element from your data structure. In your case, it is the first element of the tuple, so we access [0].

Comment: you get two elements `(2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:09,680\n']), (2, ['00:00:00,280', '00:00:08,760'])` but result should have only second value.